# How to programmatically set action for barButtonItem in swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift, selector, swift3, uibarbuttonitem

Here is what I used previously,

```
var barButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: backImgs, style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain, target: self, action: Selector("menuButtonTapped:"))
```

But there is some syntax changes for Swift 3.

Answer (score 119, accepted):

ex:-

```
navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Add", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(addTapped))
```

Comment: I would click on the up arrow but it's at 69 so we'll leave it for now.

Comment: @JackDerbis 

Answer (score 62):

Summarize the mostly used method in Swift 3 for adding action to a barButton.

1. Barbutton with text

   ```
   navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Add", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(addTapped))
   ```
2. BarButton with your own image

   ```
   navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named:"add"), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(addTapped))
   ```
3. BarButton with system image

   ```
   navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .add, target: self, action: #selector(addTapped))
   ```

Answer (score 39):

If anyone is using `customView`:

```
barButtonItem.customView?.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(onBarButtonItemClicked)))
```

Comment: This is what will work if you need to add the gesture recognizer to a bar button item when using the `customView` initializer. As far as I've found only this method signature will work (adding the gesture to the view itself/to the bar button/anything else didn't work for me).

Answer (score 14):

You just need to change your `selector` syntax as of from Swift 3 you need to specify the first parameter name of method in your function call so change your selector like this.

```
#selector(menuButtonTapped(sender:))
```

And your method should be like this.

```
func menuButtonTapped(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

}
```

Comment: From swift 3, I have to specify first parameter, but I don't need to do this.. anyway, thanks

Comment: @Bhanupriya Yes you can but for that you need to use `_` with selector `#selector(menuButtonTapped(_:))` and also need to add `_` as first parameter to your method like `func menuButtonTapped(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {` either one of the option you have to use other wise it will not work.

Comment: @Bhanupriya Are you getting what i have tell you about selector in above comment?

Comment: No, I don't need to. what I need is as follows: var barButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: backImgs, style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(menuButtonTapped))

Comment: @Bhanupriya then why you are previously try  `Selector("menuButtonTapped:")` here `:` means method contain one parameter that is the reason i have given answer this way.

Answer (score 12):

One line of code on Swift 3 for iOS 10.1:

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Add", style: .plain, target: self, action: nil)
```

Answer (score 8):

```
let barButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "backImgs"),
                                            style: .plain,
                                            target: self,
                                            action: #selector(menuButtonTapped))

// Adding button to navigation bar (rightBarButtonItem or leftBarButtonItem)
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = barButtonItem

 // Private action
@objc fileprivate func menuButtonTapped() { // body method here }
```

Answer (score 8):

If someone is looking for a way to set the action on an existing button (Swift 5):

```
if let leftBarButtonItem = navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem {
    leftBarButtonItem.target = self
    leftBarButtonItem.action = #selector(onBack(_:))
}


@IBAction func onBack(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    _ = navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
}
```

Comment: Great. It's also for Swift 4 and lower versions.

Answer (score 6):

create an extension for barbutton item.

```
 extension UINavigationItem {
    func addSettingButtonOnRight(){
       let button = UIButton(type: .Custom)
       button.setTitle("setting", forState: .Normal)
       button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(15.0)
       button.layer.cornerRadius = 5
       button.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor()
       button.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 25)
       button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(gotSettingPage), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
       let barButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: button)

       self.rightBarButtonItem = barButton
   }

   func gotSettingPage(){

   }
 }
```

And call it from viewDidLoad()

```
 self.navigationItem.addSettingButtonOnRight()
```

Answer (score 6):

In **Swift 3**, you can add UIBarButtonItem like that,

```
let addButton = UIBarButtonItem(image:UIImage(named:"your_icon_name"), style:.plain, target:self, action:#selector(YourControllerName.buttonAction(_:)))
addButton.tintColor = UIColor.white
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton
```

And handle button action like that,

```
func buttonAction(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 6):

for Swift 4 add in `viewDidLoad`:

```
navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(
    barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.add, 
    target: self, 
    action: #selector(addTransaction)
)
```

Answer (score 4):

In Swift 5

```
//For righter button item
let rightBtn = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "rightmenu"), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(onClickMethod))//Change your function name and image name here
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightBtn
//self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [rightBtn, anotherBtn] //If you want to add more buttons add like this

//For left bar button item
let leftBtn = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "rightmenu"), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(onClickMethod)) //Change your function name and image name here
self.navigationItem.leftItemsSupplementBackButton = true
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = leftBtn
//self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems = [leftBtn, anotherBtn] //If you want to add more buttons add like this

//This is your function name
@objc func onClickMethod() {
    print("Left bar button item")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make a UIBarButtonItem:

```
let rightButton: UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.done, target: self, action: #selector(LocationViewController.doneButtonClicked(_:)))
```

Add to NavigationItem:

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightButton
```

Associated function:

```
func doneButtonClicked(_ button:UIBarButtonItem!){    
    print("Done clicked")    
}
```