# Swift how to direct users to different viewcontrollers based on toolbar button clicked

Tags: ios, swift, toolbar

I programmatically created a toolbar that has 2 bar button items: `btnPlus` and `btnRating` (fixedSpace is just used to set the distance between them). What I want to do is when a user clicks on `btnPlus`, the button will direct user to the `FifthViewController` and when the user taps on `btnRating` it will direct user to the `SixthViewController`. I have the below code but how can I know which button the user has clicked in this case and based on that direct it to the relevant `viewController`? I'd appreciate any help! Thank you very much in advance!

```
navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [btnPlus, fixedSpace, btnRating]

@objc func OnbtnPlusTouched()
{
    guard let uivc = storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "FifthViewController") as? FifthViewController else {
        return
    }
    navigationController!.pushViewController(uivc, animated: true)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39768600/how-to-programmatically-set-action-for-barbuttonitem-in-swift-3/44582131

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add methods to `barButton` like this :

```
let btnPlus  = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Your Title", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(YourViewController.OnbtnPlusTouched))
```

If your using image in that then :

```
let btnPlus = UIBarButtonItem(image: "Image Name", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(YourViewController.OnbtnPlusTouched))
```

similarly you can do that for `btnRating`.

One more thing, your methods name is `OnbtnPlusTouched`, which is not good. Create methods with `lowerCamelCase` as `onBtnPlusTouched`.

To know more you can go through this helpful URL:

- https://github.com/raywenderlich/swift-style-guide

Hope this helps.